# Add confirmation popup on “Move to Trash”

Tags: posts, functions, jquery, wp-admin, javascript

I want to open javascript message "Are you sure you want to move the post to trash?"when we clicks on "Move to Trash" link in Publish box.
and when we click to OK the post go to trash or cancel to go back to the post.

I found this code on previous question. It's open the javascript message but when I click OK it's just close the popup and don't move the post to trash. What can I add to fix it?

```
CODE :

if (! empty($GLOBALS['pagenow']) && 'post.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'])
    add_action('admin_footer', 'trash_click_message');
function trash_click_message() {
    echo <<<JQUERY
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#delete-action a').unbind();
        $('#delete-action a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Are you sure you want to move the post to trash?');
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $('#save-action .spinner').hide();
                    $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                },
                1
            );
        });
    });
</script>
JQUERY;
}
```

Picture of my actuel result

[image]

UPDATE :

Thanks bergire! It's all most done. I just have one issues. I use Wordpress in english but the serveur is on France. So the confirmation popup is in french like you see in the picture.[image]

Is it a way to change labels to (indique) and (annuler) words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to *admin enqueue* this script, with *jquery* dependency:

```
jQuery( function($) {       
    $('.edit-php a.submitdelete, .post-php a.submitdelete').click( function( event ) {
        if( ! confirm( 'Are you sure you want to move the post to trash?' ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }           
    });
});
```

where we restrict the conformation on the `a.submitdelete` clicks to the `.edit-php` and `.post-php` body classes.

Hope you can adjust it to your needs, e.g. regarding i18n.

Comment: thanks Birgire. can you check the update of the post please?

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13694133/2078474) can help?

Comment: Any luck you had it working on the Gutenberg edit page too?

Answer (score 0):

```
function confirm_delete_popup() {
    global $pagenow;

    // Verifica si estás en una página que comienza con "edit.php"
    if ($pagenow === 'edit.php' || strpos($pagenow, 'edit.php?') === 0) {
        echo <<<JQUERY
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Agrega un evento click a los enlaces de eliminación en páginas de edición
    $(document).on('click', '.submitdelete', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Evita que el enlace se ejecute inmediatamente
        
        // Muestra un cuadro de diálogo de confirmación
        var respuesta = confirm("¿Estás seguro de que deseas borrar permanentemente esta página o post? Esta acción no se puede deshacer.");

        // Si el usuario hace clic en "Aceptar", redirige al enlace original
        if (respuesta) {
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
</script>
JQUERY;
    }
}

// Ejecuta el código solo en las páginas que comienzan con "edit.php"
add_action('admin_footer', 'confirm_delete_popup');
```